# web.xml URL pattern matching question for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web.xml, url-pattern

I'd like to use this kind of a pattern for my Java web app:

```
<url-pattern>/*/test.html</url-pattern>
```

and then parse the URL in the servlet to get what the value of the star is, and use that value to query a different table in the database.

However this seems to be an illegal pattern for Tomcat.
Is there any way I can achieve this without having to hard code the bit between the slashes?

(example uses in case you're wondering what the context is: `/vancouver-hotel/rooms.html`, `/seattle-hotel/rooms.html`)

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to rearrange your URL structure to `/hotels/<cityname>` and let a `HotelServlet` listen on `/hotels/*` and get the `<cityname>` as pathinfo using [`request.getPathInfo()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29). You can use the usual [`java.lang.String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) methods to parse the pathinfo further. For example a [`split("/")`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and then storing the parts as a request attribute or something else which can be accessed by business/domain objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a url rewriting filter:

http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Answer (score 0):

Easily done with a GET parameter:

```
http://localhost:8080/rooms?city=vancouver
```

Comment: Not SEO friendly. Query parameters are ignored.

Comment: Map everything to rooms and let the servlet sort things out after fetching the city out of query parameters.